# Cast [Int] to [Word8]

Tags: haskell, casting

How can I cast an int list, `[Int]` into a Word8 list, `[Word8]`. I can cast a single int using `let a = 1 :: Word8`. How can I do the same for a list of integers values? When I try I get an error.

(Aside, my main goal is to convert from `[Int] -> ByteString`, I'm using `[Word8]` as an intermediate, is there a better way to do this?)

Comment: You aren't casting an `Int` here (in fact, no `Int`s are involved); unlike in other languages, where normally a literal like `1` has a specific type, in Haskell it has the polymorphic type `Num a => a`, meaning it can be used with any numeric type. It's also defined to mean the same as `fromInteger (1 :: Integer)`, so it's a function call, not a cast. (Though the compiler will be able to optimize it down to a cast in the end.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try `fromIntegral`, the Swiss-army tool of converting between integer types: `Data.ByteString.pack (map fromIntegral [97..97 + 25])` should yield `"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" :: Data.ByteString`.

As for the question of whether this is the best way: once you have a list of `Int`s, there's not much you can do besides paying the cost of conversion. `Int`s are 32-bit machine integers with three bits reserved for tagging (I think), whereas `Word8` are 8-bit machine integers. If performance is an issue, perhaps only use `Word8`s in the first place.

Answer (score 7):

For converting between different numeric types, use [`fromIntegral`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fromIntegral). In your case you need `map fromIntegral`. Note that you may need to specify some types if from your program it's not possible to infer return type of `fromIntegral`.

For generating `ByteString`, try: `Data.ByteString.pack . map fromIntegral`.

Comment: `Data.ByteString.Char8` is probably a bad idea here - `Char` is far less efficient than `Word8` unless you *need* to go via it.